# Console.log jQuery object does not display all properties

Tags: dom, jquery-selectors, google-chrome-devtools

This question probably arises from my poor understanding of the chrome console.

On a page where jQuery is included, when I do:

```
console.log($('#content');
```

where I'm selecting some random div, I get a response looking something like:

```
[div#content, context: document, selector: "#content", jquery: "1.9.1", constructor: function, init: function…]
```

And when I click it, I see five things:

```
>0: div#content
>context: document
length: 1
selector: "#content"
>__proto__: Object[0]
```

So, what befuddles me is: If I say `$('#content').css('color', 'blue');` this works as expected. Yet, the css method of the object does not show up when I console.log it. Why is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Methods like `css` are on the jQuery object prototype. If you expand the last item in the list, `__proto__`, you will see many of the familiar jQuery methods. For more info on Object.prototype see the [docs at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype).

Comment: Should have thought of that... Thanks!